# how to prove that this positive sequence converges to 1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have a **positive** infinite sequence $a_n$ and I know that $a_n$$a_{n+1}$ converges to 1 and also $a_n$$a_{n+2}$ converges to 1.

Why does it mean that $a_n$ also converges to 1? How can I prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: By series, do you mean sequence?

Comment: Hint: Consider the limit rule of multiplication: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x) g(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x) \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)$ along with the associative and commutative laws of multiplication. What about $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n a_{n+1} a_{n+2}$?

Comment: yes a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n^2a_{n+1}a_{n+2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_na_{n+1}\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_na_{n+2}=1$$
and since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_{n+1}a_{n+2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_na_{n+1}=1,$$
 we obtain 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n^2=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{a_n^2a_{n+1}a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}a_{a+2}}=1.$$
Id est, since  $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a continuous function, we obtain:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt{a_n^2}=\sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n^2}=1,$$
which says that $\{a_n\}$ converges to $1$.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use limit arithmetic that way without first proving that $a_n$ converges?  That whole point was to proof that it's converging and only then calculate its limit (which I think is 1 but not sure how to prove it).

Comment: @OmriSoudry I did not use that $\{a_n\}$ converges, I proved it by the limit arithmetic . I proved before that $\{a_n^2\}$ converges. See please better my solution.

Comment: Thanks, but just to be sure, is there a way to prove it by somehow proving that $a_n$ is a cauchy sequence?

Comment: @OmriSoudry Maybe it's possible, but I think my solution is very smooth. גמר חתימה טובה